# Get one column from one table and join to another table from an ID

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have a query which is working but pulling through the wrong data. It pulls through two `doc_id` columns but I only need one. I just need the surname from one table to join to the other via the `patient_id`. Both tables contain `patient_id` so joining them should not be too bad but I'm notsure how to just get the one column.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM requested_appointments 
INNER JOIN patient_info ON  
       requested_appointments.patient_id=patient_info.patient_id 
WHERE requested_appointments.booked_status='N';
```

This query results in the following image:[image]

As you can see it pulls `doctor_id` through from two tables. On my web page it is displaying the `patient_info` table's `doctor_id` rather than the `requested_appointment` `doctor_id`. So essentially I need to get the surname and forename from the `patient_info` table and join it to the requested `appointment table`.

Hope this makes sense and someone can help me out!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a more exact select and alias the table names, this is not tested but some thing like this.

```
SELECT ra.doctor_id, pi.surname, pi.forename FROM requested_appointments ra INNER JOIN patient_info pi ON ra.patient_id=pi.patient_id WHERE ra.booked_status='N';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ra.*,  pi.surname, pi.forename 
FROM requested_appointments ra
INNER JOIN patient_info pi USING(patient_id)
WHERE ra.booked_status='N';
```

Comment: Thanks alot, but I get the error: Unknown Column requested_appointments.booked_status in where clause

Comment: @Josh I didn't edit WHERE clause I just copied it from your question

Comment: requested_appointments does have a booked_status column. So this error does not make sense

Comment: @Josh Try using `ra.booked_status='N'` (I edited my answer)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a qualifier to the doctor_id column in the select clause. like for ex. requested_appointments.doctor_id, patient_info.surname, patient_info.firstname. In case you have multiple tables which have same field then the way to distinguish the columns is qualifier. You can also add an alias to the tables in the following way:

select myTable.* from TABLE_A as myTable;